# Why do the images in my html email fail to load?

Tags: html, email, outlook, hotmail, image-loading

The images in my html email fail to load completely. The email was written in dreamweaver. I've tested the email on various clients: hotmail, gmail, outlook on mac and windows. The images load fine on the others, just not completely on hotmail/outlook.com. I've also hosted the images on tinypic to eradicate the possible hosting issues.

Is there any other codes I'm missing? Is it possibly the size of the images?

http://i58.tinypic.com/255kmjn.png

Answer (score 0):

Did you perhaps forget the end quote?

You show:

```
src="http://i58.tinypic.com/255kmjn.png;
```

it should be

```
src="http://i58.tinypic.com/255kmjn.png"
```

Comment: Sorry, I created that as some example code. Here's the actual one:                                          <td align="left" style="width:650px; height:216px;" valign="top"><img alt="CLIPS Newsletter – December 2014" border="0" height="216" src="http://penknifedesign-studio.com/clipsemail-march/images/header1.jpg" style="display:block;" width="650" /> </td>

Comment: Still, you need to close an src attribute with double quotes ( " ) and no semicolon ( ; ) at the end. Also, use the full "http://" path.